# Widget is not compatible in different phone

Tags: android, android-widget

I created a Widget which shows the WiFi status and information. I created and tested a phone having android version 4.0. While i am testing it with the other phones which is lower in version the text used in the widget are becoming small and scattered all the components i used in it. The layout xml i used is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wifi_background"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_status"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:textSize="11dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_on"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="11dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_notconnected"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="7dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_signal_strength"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_circle"
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="76dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/onpress_wifi_icon_circle_null"
    android:src="@drawable/toggle" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_square"
    android:layout_width="83dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/wifi_circle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/onpress_network_info_squre_null"
    android:src="@drawable/togglenetwork" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Use `sp` for `textSize` instead of `dip` or `dp`.

Comment: It does not make any difference :-(

Comment: If you can provide the desired layout's image, I think I'll be able to help you with the XML.

Comment: Please edit it. It says **![enter image description here][1]** just after the `</FrameLayout>` tag.

Comment: When I said edit it, I meant to ask you to fix the link (image description) :) Please do it so that I know what is your need and how I can fix your XML.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you put the entire layout xml code in a linera layout with orientation as Vertical ?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

Your Current Layout xml code inside....

</LinearLayout>
```

try it out..i think it should work fine!!

Comment: I tried like that but that time only able to view the background image. Text is not displaying inside.

Answer (score 0):

The layout of the ImageView is fill_parent. Probably you need to specify a size there as well.